# How to solve the writing hand html dingbat font-size issue in safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

I have this Html Dingbat ✍, I set the height in `1.5em`, Mozilla and Chrome recognizes it, but not in Safari instead, Safari added a `padding/margin` in the top and bottom of the Dingbat. example.

Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox

✍ = They recognizes the `font-size`.

Safari (at least tested in iPhone 4s)

✍ = it only added a `padding/margin` to the `top` and `bottom` of the Dingbat equal to the `font-size` that I set (`padding/margin-top-and-bottom = font-size`)

Anyone had this kind of issue? I searched here and found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, the iPhone 4s' Safari browser had this kind of issue (maybe Safari's version), I tested it in iPad mini 2, it works. Be careful when using Html charsets, symbols, dingbats, etc., you may encounter this kind of issue.